# Why would HAProxy reject traffic from one location but not another?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, haproxy

I am able to access all of the sites with no issues and our customers are placing orders without any difficulty but at one of our locations where we have a lot of users constantly hitting the site, all of a sudden they are unable to connect to one of the frontend bindings.

They are able to view the haproxy monitor page and access the sites on the other frontends.

Haproxy is not under load and I have not enabled any configuration that should restrict traffic for any reason.

Does Amazon Linux OR Haproxy have any kind of default firewall that would block large amounts of connections from a single IP address?

Here is my config:

```
global

    log 127.0.0.1 local1
    #logs are saved in /var/log and rotated to not fill up.
    #http://kvz.io/blog/2010/08/11/haproxy-logging/

    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn 50000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults

    mode http
    log global
    option httplog
    option dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8
    option redispatch

    #added to hopefully solve 400 bad request errors
    option accept-invalid-http-request

    timeout http-request 15s
    timeout queue 1m
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout client 2m
    timeout server 2m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check 5s
    retries 3

    balance roundrobin
    maxconn 100000

    stats enable
    #stats refresh 10s
    stats uri /haproxy?stats
    stats auth admin:Super187

    monitor-uri /haproxy?monitor

frontend Websites_IN
    bind 10.60.49.51:80 name http
    bind 10.60.49.51:443 name https ssl crt /etc/haproxy/haproxy_ssl.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https if { ssl_fc }
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Port:\ 443  if { ssl_fc }
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http if !{ ssl_fc }
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Port:\ 80 if !{ ssl_fc }

    acl host_Site1                       hdr(host) -m dom -i www.site1.com
    use_backend Website_Site1            if host_Site1   

    acl host_Site2                      hdr(host) -m dom -i www.site2.com
    use_backend Website_Site2           if host_Site1   



backend Website_Site1
    option httpchk GET /monitor/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ www.site1.com
    http-check expect string OK
    cookie SVRDJ insert indirect nocache
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    server Web1ZoneD 10.60.17.72:80    cookie Web1ZoneD check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 2
    server Web1ZoneE 10.60.42.156:80   cookie Web1ZoneE check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 2
    server Web2ZoneD 10.60.27.94:80    cookie Web2ZoneD check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 2
    server Web2ZoneE 10.60.35.129:80   cookie Web2ZoneE check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 2

backend Website_Site2
    option httpchk GET /monitor/ HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ www.site2.com
    http-check expect string OK
    cookie SVRDJ2 insert indirect nocache
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    server Web1ZoneD 10.60.17.72:80    cookie Web1ZoneD check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 2
    server Web1ZoneE 10.60.42.156:80   cookie Web1ZoneE check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 2
    server Web2ZoneD 10.60.27.94:80    cookie Web2ZoneD check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 2
    server Web2ZoneE 10.60.35.129:80   cookie Web2ZoneE check inter 2000 rise 2 fall 2
```

Just to include a little more detail...

The problem started the other day after working fine for 2 weeks.  When first reported, I failed over to our standby server (2 separated HAproxy instance with similar config) and it worked again for 15 hours.  I tried reverting back to a previous known working config but no change.  I added a new ACL and backend to the not working front end and presto, my users could see the NEW domain (just call it site3) but still could not see the other ones on the same frontend.  Note that all the sites are setup with host headers on the same group of servers.  I also have a couple other frontend sections on different IPs that are working fine for the same users.  Some of the sites I have setup to require basic auth, and the users will get the auth popup, but then not get the site.

I have checked the load and server is running at < 20% cpu and barely any RAM.  It is running on a m1.small ec2 instance.

I checked my iptables rules and they are empty.  I am not even able to find a iptables log on the server.  How can I tell if the firewall is on or off?

Also, I have rebooted each server several times and failed over to each one with same result.

I have logging setup to use rsyslog using this config:

```
# Provides UDP syslog reception
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514 
$UDPServerAddress 127.0.0.1

#Haproxy log stuff
#http://blog.hintcafe.com/post/33689067443/haproxy-logging-with-rsyslog-on-linux
$template Haproxy,"%msg%\n"
local1.=info -/var/log/haproxy/haproxy-info.log;Haproxy
local1.notice -/var/log/haproxy/haproxy-system.admin;Haproxy
# don't log anywhere else
local1.* ~
```

I assume this should catch all HAproxy log data.  I am not sure how to enable debug yet.

Wondering if I should just update haproxy to latest DEV version?

Here  is the result of pf -Af as requested in the comments.

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD

root         1     0  0 02:19 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/init

root         2     0  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]

root         3     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]

root         4     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0]

root         5     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u:0]

root         6     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]

root         7     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [cpuset]

root         8     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [khelper]

root         9     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [kdevtmpfs]

root        10     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [netns]

root        11     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u:1]

root        15     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [xenwatch]

root        16     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:01 [xenbus]

root        83     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [sync_supers]

root        85     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [bdi-default]

root        86     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd]

root        88     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd]

root       103     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [md]

root       201     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]

root       206     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]

root       207     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [ksmd]

root       277     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [fsnotify_mark]

root       282     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [crypto]

root       289     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld]

root       295     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [khvcd]

root       346     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:02 [kworker/0:2]

root       355     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [deferwq]

root       628     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:01 [jbd2/xvda1-8]

root       629     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-dio-unwrit]

root       668     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd -d

root       777   668  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd -d

root       787   668  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/udevd -d

root      1009     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [kauditd]

root      1130     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [flush-202:1]

root      1182     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/dhclient -q -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth

root      1225     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 auditd

root      1240     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/rsyslogd -i /var/run/syslogd.pid -c 5

rpc       1264     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 rpcbind

rpcuser   1281     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 rpc.statd

root      1305     2  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 [rpciod]

root      1308     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 rpc.idmapd

root      1315     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:07 ha_logd: read process

root      1318  1315  0 02:19 ?        00:00:06 ha_logd: write process

dbus      1338     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 dbus-daemon --system

root      1383     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:27 bash /etc/haproxy/hamonitor

root      1404     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd

ntp       1431     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 ntpd -u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g

root      1446     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:02 sendmail: accepting connections

smmsp     1453     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clien

haproxy   1465     1  0 02:19 ?        00:07:47 /usr/sbin/haproxy -D -f 
/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg -p

root      1473     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 crond

root      1483     1  0 02:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/atd

root      1503     1  0 02:19 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1

root      1507     1  0 02:19 tty2     00:00:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2

root      1509     1  0 02:19 tty3     00:00:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3

root      1511     1  0 02:19 hvc0     00:00:00 /sbin/agetty /dev/hvc0 38400 vt100-nav

root      1512     1  0 02:19 tty4     00:00:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty4

root      1514     1  0 02:19 tty5     00:00:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5

root      1516     1  0 02:19 tty6     00:00:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6

root     11917  1404  0 15:57 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]

ec2-user 11921 11917  0 15:57 ?        00:00:00 sshd: ec2-user@pts/0

ec2-user 11922 11921  0 15:57 pts/0    00:00:00 -bash

root     11945 11922  0 15:57 pts/0    00:00:00 sudo -s

root     11946 11945  0 15:57 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash

newrelic 13357     1  0 16:22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/nrsysmond -c /etc/newrelic/nrsysmond.cfg -

newrelic 13359 13357  0 16:22 ?        00:00:17 /usr/sbin/nrsysmond -c /etc/newrelic/nrsysmond.cfg -

root     30012  1383  0 21:40 ?        00:00:00 sleep 5
```

Comment: What kind of connection failures are occurring - timeouts, reset packets?  Can you do a packet capture on the HAProxy system and see if the connection attempts (TCP SYN packets) are actually arriving there?

Comment: @ShaneMadden can you give me some pointers on how to do that.  I learned a lot to just get HAProxy up and running (built and installed 1.5 DEV 19 from source), but I am not a Linux expert by any means.

Comment: In the browser it looks like a timeout, but when I raised the timeout, it seemed to just take a little longer to give the error.  We only have the problem fro the one location, every one else is able to access.

Comment: What you'll want to use for that will be `tcpdump`, and you'll want to filter down to just the IP address that's having the problem, so something like `tcpdump -i eth0 host 192.0.2.1` will show you the traffic to and from the address.  If the connection attempts don't show up there, we'll know we need to look somewhere else, possibly an internet routing issue.

Comment: This is kind odd. Can you run `ps -Af` and see what's running on the machine.  See if you can see an odd process. TCP dump like @ShaneMadden mentioned is a good way to check the traffic.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out tcpdump and will also check the ps -Af.  Unfortunately, the users started being able to see the sites again today, so I have no way to test new connections for the time being.  I assume it will act up again though.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I did a 12 hour tcpdump and have a ton of data. What am I looking for in the data?

Comment: @Rico I posted the info requested above... Any ideas?

Comment: @Developr You'll need to capture traffic from when the issue is occurring - what we're looking for at least to start is whether one of those failed requests causes any packets to be captured at all, as a timeout should mean that the server either never got the connection request or never responded to it.